# How to create a working samba PUBLIC share on Linux (smbd) for LATEST windows 10 client?

Tags: samba, windows-10, samba4, smb-conf, smbclient

As we know, latest windows 10 upgrade has made samba client refuse to sue guest account. Some organization even make it impossible to disable this bug. This make it **impossible to create a public samba share on Linux for win10 clients**.

```
You can't access this shared folder because your organization's security policies block unauthenticated guest access. These policies help protect your PC from unsafe or malicious devices on the network.
```

I have tried several solutions, like [forcing client to use SMBv3 (not working)](https://serverfault.com/questions/895570/how-to-configure-samba-to-work-with-windows-10-1709), [mapping * to an existing unix user (check_sam_security: Couldn't find user xxx in passdb.)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269643/how-do-i-map-users-with-a-samba-share). I also searched the Internet, but didn't get anything for Linux.

I have a idea like this:
Make smbd server **always tell windows "login success"**, rather than "login failed, please use guest account". But I don't know how to configure smbd to do this.

If you know something about bypassing this win10 limit, please give me a tip. thanks)

Comment: I'm working on a cracked smbd. https://github.com/recolic/samba/tree/bypass-samba-server-auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the Samba share but a new security setting under Windows 10. They specifically made it so that you cannot bypass this behaviour from the Samba side. They explain why under the section *Cause*.

> #### Symptoms
>
> In Windows 10, Windows Server 2019, or Windows Server 2016, the SMB2
> client no longer allows the following actions:
>
> - Guest account access to a remote server.
> - Fall back to the Guest account after invalid credentials are provided.
>
> SMBv2 has the following behavior in these versions of Windows:
>
> - Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Education no longer allow a user to connect to a remote share by using guest credentials by
>   default, even if the remote server requests guest credentials.
> - Windows Server 2016 Datacenter and Standard editions no longer allow a user to connect to a remote share by using guest credentials
>   by default, even if the remote server requests guest credentials.
> - Windows 10 Home and Professional editions are unchanged from their previous default behavior.
>
> If you try to connect to devices that request credentials of a guest
> instead of appropriate authenticated principals, you may receive the
> following error message:
>
> > You can't access this shared folder because your organization's security policies block unauthenticated guest access. These policies
> > help protect your PC from unsafe or malicious devices on the network.

and

> #### Cause
>
> This change in default behavior is by design and is recommended by
> Microsoft for security.
>
> A malicious computer that impersonates a legitimate file server could
> allow users to connect as guests without their knowledge. Microsoft
> recommends that you do not change this default setting. If a remote
> device is configured to use guest credentials, an administrator should
> disable guest access to that remote device and configure correct
> authentication and authorization.
>
> Windows and Windows Server have not enabled guest access or allowed
> remote users to connect as guest or anonymous users since Windows
> 2000. Only third-party remote devices might require guest access by default. Microsoft-provided operating systems do not.

and

> #### Resolution
>
> If you want to enable insecure guest access, you can configure the
> following Group Policy settings:
>
> - Open the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
> - In the console tree, select Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > Lanman Workstation.
> - For the setting, right-click Enable insecure guest logons and select Edit.
> - Select Enabled and select OK.

Source

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/guest-access-in-smb2-is-disabled-by-default

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I know this problem is caused by win10, but I would like to "crack" this win10 security feature. because as an server host-er, it's impossible to connect to user's win10 and adjust their settings. what's more, my "organization"(microsoft.com) doesn't allow me to modify this group policy at all.

Comment: It's not possible to circumvent this feature on the samba side. You can ask as often as you like, but the answer will not change. What are you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting a smbd configuration, to allow "Everyone" Read/Write access ( just like windows does). win10 doesn't accept "Guest", so I want to give access to every possible username/password combination.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the "Everyone" role with Read or Read/Write it will allow you to connect without authenticating. Also remember the Share permissions don't override the NTFS permissions for files, so assign Everyone to Read/Write on the folders too (not just the share permissions).

Here's a tutorial
https://websiteforstudents.com/create-shares-everyone-full-access-windows-10-server/

Comment: I realized my latest modification removed "Linux smbd" keywords... Sorry for the mistake, but I'm looking for a solution with Linux samba server...